# ServerSocket Java Установка любого адреса

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, ip

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность установить произвольный (а не только localhost) адрес, который будет приниматься в

```
ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)
```

Т.е.

```
bindAddr = InetAddress.getByName("www.ya.ru")
```

например сделать таким? Чтобы запросы с локальной машины при запросе на яндекс, например, обрабатывались моим сервером, а не сразу отправлялись на ya.ru.

Answer (score 1):

Bind address задает адрес **с которого** можно подключаться к данному серверу. Чтобы разрешить подключение с любого адреса, там указывается `0.0.0.0:0`

Перехватывать пакеты, адресованные другому серверу вы не можете в принципе. Только если организуете какой-нибудь прокси. Т.е. клиент **явно** подключается к вашему серверу, но говорит, что ему нужно на яндекс

Comment: а не могли бы вы навести меня на что-нибудь полезное по теме прокси-сервера, чтобы клиент явно подключился к моему серверу. Все интернеты я еще не облазил, но половину точно и чего то стоящего пока не нашел.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр А какая конечная цель?

Comment: обработка интернет запросов, фильтр определенных сайтов, ну и соответственно при прохождение всех "условий" предоставление клиенту искомую информацию(опять же, возможно разворачивание данной информации, исправлении, а затем заворачивании обратно и передача клиенту). То есть некая "прослойка" между клиентом и большим и могучим интернетом.@AntonShchyrov

Comment: @МишаковАлександр Какое "исправление" в https? На любом роутере есть фаерволл и фильтр трафика. Чем он не угодил?

Comment: да, с https будут проблемы. Антон, хотелось бы написать подобную вещь с целью лучше понять данный вопрос. Поэтому фаервол и фильтр трафика не угодили тем, что они уже есть :)

Answer (score 1):

на яве вы ничего такого не сделаете. Тут чистое сетевое администрирование. Если хотите заворачивать трафик с локальной машины то редактируйте файл hosts операционой системы.Если нужно заворачивать трафик в локальной сети то тут вам пользоватся ДНС сервером и (или) фаєрволом.